# surviving iterative deletion of strictly dominated strategies and determining all pure and mixed strategy NE

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcxs.png)

I am trying to solve this and used the following:

\begin{bmatrix}(0,1)&(0,0)&(10,4/5)\\(3,1)&(1,2)&(0,1)\\(1,5/2)&(2,3/2)&(0,2)\end{bmatrix}, where the columns represent Miles and the rows represent Stevie. Note that, the first column is L, second column is C and the third column is R. The first row isT, the second row is H and the third row is B.

*I hope that this is understandable. I do not know how to insert matrix like this in math stack exchange.*

Moving on to my analysis:

Consider R and consider s_2 = (p, 1-p, 0)

Then we have:

1*p + 0*(1-p) > 4/5

1*p + 2(1-p) > 1

5/2 *p + 3/2 *(1-p) > 2

Solving this, we obtain that  1/2 < p < 1.

Therefore, we can eliminate R and thereafter we can eliminate T.

By doing this, I am left with a 2 by 2 matrix and in my opinion, these are the strategies that survive the iterative deletion of strictly dominated strategies.

My question is, am I correct?

For the second part of the question, I defined a mixed strategies for Stevies (a, 1-a) and for Miles (b, 1-b).

Solving the following equations:

3a + 1(1-a) = 1a + 2*(1-a) --> a = 1/3

and

1*b + 2*(1-b) = 5/2 *b + 3/2 *(1-b) --> b = 1/2

Am I doing the right thing now? I can observe that there are no pure strategies here. Therefore, I went on determining the mixed nash equilibrieum. Now that I have the values for a and b. What is the next thing left to do to show that there exist a mixed NE or not?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Thanks, changed it a bit